# When scraping the page with selenium and beautiful soup, I will get duplicates of some results

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a page with selenium and beautiful soup and I'm getting duplicates when I use a for loop to change the page URL and I have no idea why.
This is my code

```
import json
import requests
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from chromedriver_py import binary_path # this will get you the path variable
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd

teams = []
home_team = []
away_team = []
results_away = []
results_home = []
results_away1 = []
results_home1 = []
list3_away = []
list3_home = []
odds = []
odds_sub = []
odds_sub1 = []
days = ['20160826',
'20160827',
'20160901',
]
for date in days:
    header = {"user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
    url = 'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/betting-odds/college-football/totals/1st-half/?date='+date
    page = requests.get(url, headers = header)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    #### Selenium scraper for odds
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(lambda d: d.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-vertical-sbid="238"]'))
    for a in elements:
        odds.append(a.text)
    for a in odds:
        string = a.split('''\n''', 1)[0]
        mod_string = string[:-4]
        odds_sub.append(mod_string)
    driver.quit()

    ## All teams
    for el in soup.find_all('span', class_='participantBox-3ar9Y'):
        teams.append(el.text)

    ### Away result
    for s in soup.find_all(class_="scoreboard-1TXQV"):
        for a in s.select(".scoreboardColumn-2OtpR > div:nth-of-type(1)")[:2]:
            results_away.append(a.text)
    for a in results_away:
        if a == '-':
            a= a.replace(a, '10000')
        results_away1.append(a)
    results_away1 = [int(i) for i in results_away1]

    for i in range(0, len(results_away1)-1, 2):
        firstnum = results_away1[i]
        secondnum = results_away1[i+1]
        sumnum = firstnum + secondnum
        list3_away.append(sumnum)

    ### Home results
    for s in soup.find_all(class_="scoreboard-1TXQV"):
        for a in s.select(".scoreboardColumn-2OtpR > div:nth-of-type(2)")[:2]:
            results_home.append(a.text)
    for a in results_home:
        if a == '-':
            a= a.replace(a, '10000')
        results_home1.append(a)
    results_home1 = [int(i) for i in results_home1]

    for i in range(0, len(results_home1)-1, 2):
        firstnum = results_home1[i]
        secondnum = results_home1[i+1]
        sumnum = firstnum + secondnum
        list3_home.append(sumnum)
    time.sleep(7)

#### Create lists for away and home teams
for team in teams[::2]:
    away_team.append(team)
for team in teams[1::2]:
    home_team.append(team)

print(home_team)
print('*****')
print(away_team)
print('*****')
print(list3_home)
print('*****')
print(list3_away)
print('*****')
print(odds_sub)
print('*****')
```

I receive results like this:

```
['California', 'North Dakota State', '(13) Louisville', 'Wake Forest', 'Central Michigan', 'Cincinnati', 'Connecticut', 'Florida International', '(21) Tennessee', 'North Carolina State', 'Western Kentucky', 'Vanderbilt', '(19) Utah', 'Utah State', 'Minnesota', 'New Mexico', 'Idaho', 'UNLV']
*****
['Hawaii', 'Charleston Southern', 'Charlotte', 'Tulane', 'Presbyterian', 'Tennessee-Martin', 'Maine', 'Indiana', 'Appalachian State', 'William & Mary', 'Rice', 'South Carolina', 'Southern Utah', 'Weber State', 'Oregon State', 'South Dakota', 'Montana State', 'Jackson State']
*****
[34, 34, 34, 3, 34, 34, 3, 34, 3, 56, 7, 14, 6, 7, 10, 3, 28, 30, 10, 17, 21, 17, 35, 20, 42]
*****
[14, 14, 14, 3, 14, 14, 3, 14, 3, 0, 3, 3, 7, 7, 12, 13, 7, 7, 0, 0, 6, 14, 14, 10, 10]
*****
['34', '34', '', '34', '', '34½', '21½', '', '', '', '32', '31', '', '33½', '20', '', '', '28', '', '', '']
*****
```

For example list3_home has 7 results at the beginning duplicated, odds_sub list has 3 duplicates at the beginning etc.

Comment: There's multiple odds for each game. Which one do you want?

Comment: Secondly, I think your issue is you are appending into a list, and then from that list iterating through and then appending again, so you're exponentially growing the list. I have a better way to get this data, but I need to know which odds so you want.

Comment: and by multiple odds, I mean there's BetOnline, BookMaker, etc. Which one ar you after?

Comment: pinnacle only, so only data with data-vertical-sbid="238" attribute.
Yeah, I'm quite new to this, so I know it's kinda messy code

Comment: no worries! It's part of learning. There is an api (it's a little tricky with the query parameters), but it's a bit more efficient. I'll have a solution for you in a few minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so see if this works. There's quite a bit of parameter ids to use in the query if you want other data. But this will get you the 1st half stuff. I *think* I identified the correct id for Pinnacle.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
from calendar import timegm

days = ['20160826',
'20160827',
'20160901',
'20200912',
]


homeTeam_list = []
awayTeam_list = []
homeScore_list = []
awayScore_list = []

odds_list = []


url = 'https://www.sportsbookreview.com/ms-odds-v2/odds-v2-service'
header = {"user-agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36"}
   
for date in days:
    print(date)
    date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y%m%d')
    year = date_time_obj.year
    month = date_time_obj.month
    day = date_time_obj.day
    
    dt = datetime(year,month,day,0,0)
    tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=0))
    epochtime = timegm(dt.replace(tzinfo=tz).utctimetuple()) *1000

    queryStr_participants = 'query=%7B+eventsByDateByLeagueGroup(+es:+[%22in-progress%22,+%22scheduled%22,+%22complete%22,+%22suspended%22,+%22delayed%22,+%22postponed%22,+%22retired%22,+%22canceled%22],+leagueGroups:+[%7B+mtid:+398,+lid:+6,+spid:+4+%7D],+providerAcountOpener:+3,+hoursRange:+25,+showEmptyEvents:+false,+marketTypeLayout:+%22PARTICIPANTS%22,+ic:+false,+startDate:+' + str(int(epochtime)) + ',+timezoneOffset:+-4,+nof:+true,+hl:+true,+sort:+%7Bby:+[%22lid%22,+%22dt%22,+%22des%22],+order:+ASC%7D+)+%7B+events+%7B+eid+lid+spid+des+dt+es+rid+ic+ven+tvs+cit+cou+st+sta+hl+seid+writeingame+plays(pgid:+2,+limitLastSeq:+3,+pgidWhenFinished:+-1)+%7B+eid+sqid+siid+gid+nam+val+tim+%7D+scores+%7B+partid+val+eid+pn+sequence+%7D+participants+%7B+eid+partid+partbeid+psid+ih+rot+tr+sppil+sppic+startingPitcher+%7B+fn+lnam+%7D+source+%7B+...+on+Player+%7B+pid+fn+lnam+%7D+...+on+Team+%7B+tmid+lid+tmblid+nam+nn+sn+abbr+cit+senam+imageurl+%7D+...+on+ParticipantGroup+%7B+partgid+nam+lid+participants+%7B+eid+partid+psid+ih+rot+source+%7B+...+on+Player+%7B+pid+fn+lnam+%7D+...+on+Team+%7B+tmid+lid+nam+nn+sn+abbr+cit+%7D+%7D+%7D+%7D+%7D+%7D+marketTypes+%7B+mtid+spid+nam+des+settings+%7B+sitid+did+alias+format+template+sort+url+%7D+%7D++eventGroup+%7B+egid+nam+%7D+statistics(sgid:+3,+sgidWhenFinished:+4)+%7B+val+eid+nam+partid+pid+typ+siid+sequence+%7D+league+%7B+lid+nam+rid+spid+sn+settings+%7B+alias+rotation+ord+shortnamebreakpoint+matchupline+%7D+%7D+%7D+maxSequences+%7B+events:+eventsMaxSequence+scores:+scoresMaxSequence+currentLines:+linesMaxSequence+statistics:+statisticsMaxSequence+plays:+playsMaxSequence+consensus:+consensusMaxSequence+%7D+%7D+%7D'
    jsonData_participants = requests.get(url, headers = header, params=queryStr_participants).json()



    events = jsonData_participants['data']['eventsByDateByLeagueGroup']['events']
    
    for event in events:
        des = event['des'].split('@')
        if event['es'] != 'complete':
            print(' @ '.join(des), ' - ', event['es'])
            continue
        else:    
            print(' @ '.join(des))
        eventId = str(event['eid'])
        queryStr_odds = 'query=%7B+currentLines(eid:+['+eventId+'],+mtid:+[398],+marketTypeLayout:+%22PARTICIPANTS%22,+catid:+133)+openingLines(eid:+['+eventId+'],+mtid:+[398],+marketTypeLayout:+%22PARTICIPANTS%22,+paid:+3)+bestLines(catid:+133,+eid:+['+eventId+'],+mtid:+[398])+consensus(eid:+['+eventId+'],+mtid:+[398])+%7B+eid+mtid+boid+partid+sbid+bb+paid+lineid+wag+perc+vol+tvol+sequence+tim+%7D+maxSequences+%7B+events:+eventsMaxSequence+scores:+scoresMaxSequence+currentLines:+linesMaxSequence+statistics:+statisticsMaxSequence+plays:+playsMaxSequence+consensus:+consensusMaxSequence+%7D+%7D'
        jsonData_odds = requests.get(url, headers = header, params=queryStr_odds).json()
        
        pinnacle_id = 20
        currentLines = jsonData_odds['data']['currentLines']
        for currentLine in currentLines:
            if currentLine['paid'] == pinnacle_id:
                odds = currentLine['adj']
                break
            else:
                odds = None
        
        
        teamIds = {}
        for team in event['participants']:
            teamIds[team['source']['tmid']] = team['source']['nam']
        
        
        scores = pd.json_normalize(event['scores'])
        scores['team_name'] = scores['partid'].map(teamIds)
        
        awayTeam = event['participants'][0]['source']['nam']
        homeTeam = event['participants'][1]['source']['nam']
    
        awayScore = scores[(scores['team_name'] == awayTeam) & (scores['pn'] <= 2)]['val'].astype(int).sum()
        homeScore = scores[(scores['team_name'] == homeTeam) & (scores['pn'] <= 2)]['val'].astype(int).sum()
    
    
        homeTeam_list.append(homeTeam)
        awayTeam_list.append(awayTeam)
        
        homeScore_list.append(homeScore)
        awayScore_list.append(awayScore)
        
        odds_list.append(odds)

print(homeTeam_list)
print('*****')
print(awayTeam_list)
print('*****')
print(homeScore_list)
print('*****')
print(awayScore_list)
print('*****')
print(odds_list)
print('*****')
```

**Output:**

```
['California', 'Charleston Southern', 'Charlotte', 'Maine', 'Presbyterian', 'Tennessee-Martin', 'Wake Forest', 'Tennessee', 'Florida International', 'North Carolina State', 'Rice', 'Vanderbilt', 'Southern Utah', 'Weber State', 'Montana State', 'Oregon State', 'South Dakota', 'Jackson State']
*****
['Hawaii', 'North Dakota State', 'Louisville', 'Connecticut', 'Central Michigan', 'Cincinnati', 'Tulane', 'Appalachian State', 'Indiana', 'William & Mary', 'Western Kentucky', 'South Carolina', 'Utah', 'Utah State', 'Idaho', 'Minnesota', 'New Mexico', 'UNLV']
*****
[34, 3, 0, 7, 3, 7, 7, 3, 10, 28, 7, 10, 0, 6, 10, 14, 14, 10]
*****
[14, 3, 56, 7, 14, 6, 3, 13, 12, 7, 30, 0, 17, 21, 20, 17, 35, 42]
*****
[34, 34, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 31, 32, 32, 32, 21, 21, 21, 21, 28, 28, 28]
*****
```

Comment: wow, yeah this works :) However, I wanted to scrape all games not just those with pinnacle odds. So if a game doesn't have pinnacle odds it would just have '-' or empty string

Comment: I changed the parameters a bit for different dates '20200912', '20200911' and got error odds_list.append(odds)
NameError: name 'odds' is not defined
Then I moved that last odds appending and received a different error:
 in <module>
    scores['team_name'] = scores['partid'].map(teamIds), in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
 in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'partid'

Comment: ok. let me try those 2 dates and see what needs to be altered

Comment: ah ok. That's because there are no line for Pinnacle. I'll fix that.

Comment: The other error is because Tulsa @ Oklahoma State game was postponed, there's no score for it. So I'll fix that too

Comment: I receive a lot of NONE, it seems it's an issue with odds which have .5. For example match 
Coastal Carolina Chanticleers vs Kansas Jayhawks ha line 27.5 but it was scraped as NONE. I was checking the code and I can't find an issue because adj is correct when scraping for odds

Comment: ok. I'm just trying to figure out the id/code that corresponds to pinnacle. Try it now.

Comment: it works now, thanks. Interesting approach, I will check it more in detail how you did it. Thanks again for a big help